# SQL statment, Sum the number of occurrences, Group them and Order them from highest to lowest according to the number of occurrences

Tags: sql-server

I am having trouble creating a report by pulling information from my database using sql-server. I have 3 tables: Incident, Action and Agency.

Within the Incident table I have attributes such as a

```
primary key (incident_id) 
and others (status and action_id).
```

In my Action table I have the

```
foreign keys (incident_id and agency_id) 
a primary key (action_id).
```

In my

```
Agency table
```

I have a

```
primary key (agency_id) 
and other attributes such as (agency_name and agency_type).
```

I need an sql statement that groups according to type, sums the number of actions an incident has and orders them from highest to lowest, where the status is closed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks for your time.

Comment: mysql + sql-server. Pick one please.

Comment: "I need an sql statement that...". That's not the right approach to get help. You should show us that you've made some effort, display your code and tell us what issues you have been facing in order to get help and avoid downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using MySQL syntax, the following should help get you along the way:

```
SELECT ag.agency_type, count(ac.action_id)
FROM 
incident AS i INNER JOIN 
action AS ac ON i.incident_id=ac.incident_id INNER JOIN
agency AS ag ON ac.agency_id=ag.agency_id
WHERE i.status='Closed'
GROUP BY ag.agency_type
ORDER BY count(ac.action_id) DESC;
```